# org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I have tried several answers on stackoverflow but can't figure it out how to make it work

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git' to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties failed:

```
Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key
```

Action:

Update your application's configuration

This is the application.properties file

```
server.port=8881
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@bitbucket.org:my_user/my_repo.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=*configs
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignore-local-ssh-settings=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.passphrase=
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key=-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAdzc2gtcn\
NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAYEAtl/5Hbu/bHQsddLTMI7Ph0G86/xOaq/xqs3CyQyNCCh2lzz+oeBe\
lZbG16JQ4HrhA+q9vT1xIISGS8XEf46FvbulBl473rOlOk50xTQfA5a/6CHZ2PXKq1oU2T\
PyILIB4MDWBYUDBWUBDUWNDUNWUNDUWNDUWNUDNWUBDBWWVWYXVBWB64+lhKmnyEnSaHZm\
2Jxe2RdrpTYn81WsgJKtvy7McR0eo6vGejCVTg+0aOvKw0XX5Dwy06uNwGjjWSaN0WzU7O\
Uu/Sh1gQF++lCu5IO0u/hAXzhrOcTLosNw1irNLBO9tskk/rhZ2ufgjsFZkJ0xyZGwiTD0\
v6nd+wsmf0k+KGtr8U1tf8Aw1JQ2U3+WJVxZRXmodHijuPie0b6pEpPu3xqHEvMjfKiYQt\
mH/R3tVh1FRJa88KkUt6GAU/Brh6Cczf+LLUymZb5sM0tCNJ9pWbKZFeme92DDN3+ul/Wt\
tGXpCDoljU+BrosvasO2bkA58PPH7OA0Wmdtt7h5AAAFkLGFLOWxhSzlAAAAB3NzaC1yc2\
EAAAGBALZf+R27v2x0LHXS0zCOz4dBvOv8Tmqv8arNwskMjQgodpc8/qHgXpWWxteiUOB6\
4QPqvb09cSCEhkvFxH+Ohb27pQZeO96zpTpOdMU0HwOWv+gh2dj1yqtaFNkz8iCyAeDBqx\
t7gTkCxigN+keGSk5LniMol6EqXIPHCiITCyF8NjrhHOuPpYSpp8hJ0mh2ZticXtkXa6U2\
J/NVrICSrb8uzHEdHqOrxnowlU4PtGjrysNF1+Q8MtOrjcBo41kmjdFs1OzlLv0odYEBfv\
pQruSDtLv4QF84aznEy6LDcNYqzSwTvbbJJP64Wdrn4I7BWZCdMcmRsIkw9L+p3fsLJn9J\
Pihra/FNbX/AMNSUNlN/liVcWUV5qHR4o7j4ntG+qRKT7t8ahxLzI3yomELZh/0d7VYdRU\
SWvPCpFLehgFPwa4egnM3/iy1MpmW+bDNLQjSfaVmymRXpnvdgwzd/rpf1rbRl6Qg6JY1P\
ga6LL2rDtm5AOfDzx+zgNFpnbbe4eQAAAAMBAAEAAAGAGfxOyJfJzLA47YjeopqWo1UQkC\
dhHP541rd+u5rYNYNecmo0deg8UeAr8Oml0HZxvVcjNeWdSt7XK9DAENTD5abo+qFOsoqy\
Tj6DkN2+VYqTSYYZPjq3Z/br5Y7rPxFeByJRORc98Fue1HI5aRuPVtybabMM99/LUtN3dC\
d2fIzwRS9yKXZMRTzPNVCfdFb6jH6rXQ9jPSUcSCW68I71xrnqU2usw/Fj1GE7xOWj9Rcz\
yuMWweR58YWGXUYXEBDGEUY2GEUYXG2Y2EBXYEFYTXBF2YTBEFY2FEXF3XY3YFEXYF3X8f\
TpiVgqxBuF+d92igh7qTnT2zgpHRz7L7NzHdirIw7Sso9yk2CcHfcz+ntt9HtwKQId6tZT\
3eeAtkHYeWaBuZXlWJAiOHLPaQA9Jid0ZVf+NE0xfa6OZMQf++S5X/Q/d6NiC6F4URUGoG\
CkcQg8Q2uKEvhbaDaFkbZGyuavpeG6YC0OPWQvwaYgCzKOA4/MXSu3nRpnXUGZ0EKhAAAA\
wF5UyJZJaYSwDIsBFIkEwmzL/jLo66xcaaOl7sMQLqVIdWkT14E6dPiYXn5vexy3DaoAoZ\
2Z3xszEnLlzQ36HTrKLWyZdR9nAwQtz2q1+GpywDDao2DclAWQvQaCUuMQOK94y3ECkGIy\
DOOVhox/mlbFBONR3xF5K+Th8uq96kqi51MAqqkcdL6/zNMFIBJT+w2KoQBVe3PFn3TFfU\
eJajcOI3I6aBwgxPd2YPrSysPHIBqLnJAMfXPocW9XBb1VPgAAAMEA8EWQBzUgeevti8BZ\
8YBw2HSqZXKi+8rqrM4QxVW2EybrGSwIhzDTSwwK8vOw8HT+gcj7z8jltLqCBt/Zufihzg\
jNtoe+v9VKEuH8jd6xb1apJzR3DKyJgpBaDCCg75xIj++Qb/horE+WolcbCAjLHZo/hW+p\
nGWYd/eX3C2jCTCLmAp38lsP/HHLt0JASd5Hvg031z5fzWjMLvBOiDM2yFWozcaRsi+FZn\
qPpE5aMTyLRx+z8kA9s/Zp9Xf6SCDFAAAAwQDCUC8gfMMuWotFgFfJfjDAdfiyfAsGDRu4\
d3J3NPLyqG9YfanjvfI8ezRFRFRFRFRFRFRFFRFRBVGBGBBGBGJtDKcsJaS2Jzu/PpvVcx\
EngcryKis+GWYXTBYTWFEYBXWGYEXTGWYTGEYXGWYUEGUWGUEBWHUYXGUYGXUYBGZjyYt6\
wTOAKcfstv885VfKvGBBGBGBGBGBGBRFRFRFRFRFFDDSDWWDEDQfFtG/8lPmY8UqliKd7L\
SxX6llZwFWzCUAAAAWVmlwd.HXGUYWGUYXUYBGUYXGEUY3GBEUYXG3UYEG3UXGECAwQF\n\
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your private key (which you should no longer use for anything now that is has been exposed publicly) is not an RSA key, which is the only key type that Spring Cloud Config supports.

In other words: Only private keys that start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` are supported.

There are some more details in the reference documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_authentication

Comment: Thanks, and I have manipulated this key before posting here.